# JNA getting back a byte array

Tags: java, c, pointers, jna

I have a library developed in C that successfully decompresses an LZMA encoded file. The signature for the file is a pointer to the data, the compressed, decompressed, and an 'out' field for the error code. The return value is a pointer to the array (or null if it fails).

The function in C looks similar to this:

```
char* decompressLZMA(const char *lzmaData, int compressedSize, int uncompressedSize, t_status_codes *statusCode);
```

I've tried using pointers and memory from other examples but they are not working.

How do I properly pass a byte array and pointer in to get data back?

This is my interface:

```
public interface LZMALibrary extends Library {
    Memory lzma_uncompress(Memory lzma_data, int compressed_size, int uncompressed_size, Pointer status_code);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I wanted to make a pointer of the 'Memory' class instead. The solution that is working for me right now is to create Pointer objects, and then the library will fill up the pointers, and I get them back and handle it appropriately.

My interface turned to:

```
public interface LZMALibrary extends Library {
    Pointer lzma_uncompress(Pointer lzma_data, int compressed_size, int uncompressed_size, Pointer status_code);
}
```

From there I am able to write in the data:

```
Pointer ptr = new Memory(lzmaData.length);
ptr.write(0, lzmaData, 0, lzmaData.length);
```

I also need the pointer that will be written to:

```
Pointer errorStatus = new Memory(4);
```

Then I can call the function to get a pointer back, and read that pointer if it's not null:

```
Pointer p = lzmaLib.lzma_uncompress(ptr, lzmaData.length, DECOMPRESSED_LENGTH, errorStatus); // DECOMPRESSED_LENGTH is a constant.

if (p != null) {
    byte[] decompressedData = p.getByteArray(0, DECOMPRESSED_LENGTH);
    System.out.println(new String(decompressedData, "ASCII")); // My data is ASCII text.
}

if (errorStatus != null) {
    int errorStatusCode = errorStatus.getInt(0);
    System.out.println("Error code: " + errorStatusCode);
}
```

This appears to have solved my problem. I am very new to JNA so hopefully I am not missing anything.

If there's any possible errors I might run into, please feel free to post on how to correct it.

Comment: `IntByReference` is provided for when the native call "returns" something via a parameter passed by reference.  That class will take care of the memory allocation for you and you get back the value with a call to `getValue()`.

Comment: Presumably you need to free the returned memory at some point.

Comment: @technomage By that, do you mean that when the Pointer is garbage collected, the memory it points to is not freed? I thought it was freed when finalize() is called on the Pointer, but I could be completely wrong.

Comment: After looking at the source code for Pointer, there isn't a finalize method (as of posting on this date), I'll update my post.

Comment: How would `Pointer` even know how to free the memory it was given from some arbitrary source?  It's expected that _you_ know how the memory needs to be disposed of, and that _you_ know the native method you need to call to free it.

Comment: @technomage If we assume directly C, on garbage collection it could just call free() natively from any arbitrary source if there was an agreement with the user to not call free() on their end (and just call it from the finalizer). I would not personally choose this option though even if it was available. I read in another SO question that Pointer was supposed to free itself, so that's likely where the misconception came from.